# jquery UI tabs select tab without triggering the select event

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm a complete newb to jquery so sorry in advance if im speaking jibberish.

What I want to do is programatically select a tab in javascript on pageload without triggering the selected event.

The selected event does a postback to the tabitems url, so when I select a tab it just loops postbacks over and over again.

Edit:

To clearify, after I click the tab that does a postback, I need to visually represent for the user that the tab is selected, without triggering yet another postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by initializing the selected: attribute instead of using tabs("select",i).
I tried it at first as well but it didn't work because of some other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

try using the select function like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myTabs").tabs("select", 1)
});
```

This will select the tab at index 1 for the collection of tabs called #myTabs.  Hope this helps.

Comment: It selects it but still fires the select event which I must prevent somehow. However I managed to solve the problem, kinda.